# How to take anova in this simple data?

Tags: r, anova

I want to test the miles per gallon which a test driver got for six tankfuls each of three kinds of gasoline:

The data is:

```
gasoline <- c(28, 23, 26, 31, 14, 29,21,31, 32, 19, 27, 16,24, 17, 21, 31, 22, 18)
types <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

My anova code is:

```
# Compute the analysis of variance
res.aov <- aov(gasoline ~ types)
# Summary of the analysis
summary(res.aov)
```

This code gives me
[image]

But it looks obviously wrong. Since I have three types, the degree of freedom should be 2, not 1. Why my codes failed?

Comment: How about  `aov(gasoline ~ as.factor(types))` ?

Comment: @maydin Yeah, you are correct. What happened?

Comment: You need to pass the groups as factor or character into the function. But not as numeric values.